# count similar rows and sort list

Tags: vba, excel

Good Afternoon everyone!
I do not have a code example yet, because I am actually stuck with the solution itself. This why I am asking at least for an idea how to solve the following issue.
What I need is to count similar cell values in A column and sort it according to number of similarities.

A visual example:

```
JustAValue001
JustAValue001
JustAValue001
AnotherValue002
AnotherValue002
ThirdValue003
ThirdValue003
ThirdValue003
ThirdValue003
```

What I want to achieve is actually sort this list by the number of similar values. So, the correct one should look like this:

```
ThirdValue003
ThirdValue003
ThirdValue003
ThirdValue003
JustAValue001
JustAValue001
JustAValue001
AnotherValue002
AnotherValue002
```

Sorting so that the highest count of data is first, followed by the second highest, until it gets to the fewest at the bottom

Will appreciate any good Idea.
Kind Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by similar? A pattern of some sort would need to be identified

Comment: use a helper column with a simple "CountIF" formula and sort based on the helper column.  That's going to be the simplest solution.

Comment: alright, looks like it will work. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I see that is the basic sort functionality. I put you input sequence in Excel and clicked on Sort from Z to A and it has given me the output you asked for. Please tell us a bit more clear

Try the Below Code. It worked Perfectly for me even though its a bit big

```
    Sub HighOnTop()
    Dim uniqueValues()
    Dim uniqValuesCounts()
    Dim TotalUniqueCount
    'Writing Unique values to Column C
    Sheets("UrSheet").Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Columns( _
            "A:A"), CopyToRange:=Range("C1"), Unique:=True
      I = 0
      Do While (Cells(I + 1, 3).Value <> "")
      I = I + 1

      Loop
      TotalUniqueCount = I
     ReDim uniqueValues(TotalUniqueCount - 1)
     ReDim uniqValuesCount(TotalUniqueCount - 1)

     For j = 1 To TotalUniqueCount - 1
     uniqueValues(j) = Cells(j + 1, 3)
     uniqValuesCount(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), uniqueValues(j))
     Next
     Set x = Worksheets.Add
     x.Name = "Temp"
     x.Activate
     For k = 1 To TotalUniqueCount - 1
     Cells(k, 1) = uniqueValues(k)
     Cells(k, 2) = uniqValuesCount(k)
     Next
     Columns("B:B").Select
     x.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        x.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With x.Sort
            .SetRange Range("A:B")
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        For j = 1 To TotalUniqueCount - 1
        uniqueValues(j) = Cells(j, 1)
        uniqValuesCount(j) = Cells(j, 2)
        Next
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     x.Delete
     Sheets("UrSheet").Activate
     p = 2
     For l = 1 To TotalUniqueCount - 1
        For m = 1 To uniqValuesCount(l)
         Cells(p, 1) = uniqueValues(l)
         p = p + 1
        Next
     Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think that's just an artifact of the fake data posted.  It looks like the OP is trying to sort so that the highest count of data is first, followed by the second highest, yada, yada, yada until it gets to the fewest at the bottom.

Comment: that is a correct explanation of the actual problem, will fix my main post in some minutes